# Identify last record in CASE

Tags: sql

Probably an easy one... I have a SQL query along the lines...

```
SELECT a,
          CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
               WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
               ELSE 'other'
          END
    FROM test;
```

(from the docs)

I want to identify the last record in the set and act on that condition.

Comment: Last, in which order? Use ORDER BY to specify order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios from what you have explained in your question.

One of them is the one in which for the max value found in column `a` you want to display a certain message:

```
SELECT
    a
    , CASE
        WHEN a = 1 THEN 'ONE'
        WHEN a = 2 THEN 'TWO'
        WHEN a = (SELECT MAX(a) FROM test) THEN 'MAX'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
     END
FROM TEST;
```

The other possible scenario is that only for the last record in the table you want to display that certain message. And in that scenario your query needs to change to:

```
SELECT
    a
    , CASE
        WHEN a = 1 THEN 'ONE'
        WHEN a = 2 THEN 'TWO'
        WHEN a = (SELECT TOP 1 a FROM TEST ORDER BY a DESC) THEN 'MAX'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
     END
FROM TEST
ORDER BY A;
```

Comment: But the answer is helpful anyway. If OP wants a specific order he can use `WHEN a = (SELECT TOP 1 a FROM test ORDER BY Column DESC) THEN 'LAST'` (presuming sql-server)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I understand what you mean, but I interpreted it differently based on the query pattern. It is true that you scenario is also possible, in which case `TimSchmelter's` adjustment would be in order. I will update my answer with this second possible scenario.

Comment: Doesn't the amendment suggested by @TimSchmelter sort the column by value?  I am looking to act differently on the last index, instead of the smallest value.

Comment: @froodley Do you have a primary key column on the table? Without a primary key or a `ORDER BY` clause you can't determine (and you don't have this guaranteed by a RDBSM) the same order based on multiple query executions.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, yeah, that's correct, I believe either of the suggestions would work operating against a standard primary key.  I was hoping for something more general, like 'WHEN LAST(a) ...', but I can see that this is the correct approach.

In this case, the code ought to be,
<code>
SELECT
    a
    , CASE
        WHEN idx = 1 THEN 'ONE'
        WHEN idx = 2 THEN 'TWO'
        WHEN idx = (SELECT TOP 1 idx FROM TEST ORDER BY idx DESC) THEN 'MAX'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
     END
FROM TEST
ORDER BY A;
</code>

...no?

Comment: @froodley A really good article about `ORDER BY` [**Expecting Order without ORDER BY**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx) and **YES**, that is what your code should be.

Comment: Great!  If you can modify your answer, I'll upvote and close the question.  Thanks for the resource as well.

Comment: @froodley The second query is the one you want, except for the name of the column verified in the `CASE` as per the query you posted in the comments. This does not create any difference for other readers, only for you (so you know to change the name of the column you're testing). Also, the answer matches the column you checked in your question so in order for things to be `in sync` you would need to change the question as well.